# Failed to delete the database sync agent

Tags: azure-sql-database

Failed to delete the database: DBName.
ErrorCode: 400
ErrorMessage: Database 'DBSync' cannot be deleted because it is used as a sync metadata database which still contains sync groups and/or sync agents.

We dont have access to the VM in which sync was installed , any way to force delete DB.

Comment: this happens because there are connections, in Azure Data Studio connect your db and when you delete you have an option, I think below, to close all connections

Answer (score 0):

As @Miguel said, we should close all connections of the db, then we can  delete the database. We can use SSMS to do that.

Comment: Hi@Mohit parkash, Kindly let me know if you need more information.